# Emails from Email Service

Tags: apex-email-service

Where can I find the old emails which were sent to an Email Service if I am not storing them myself ? Will they have any attachment that they came with ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the emailmessage object records? and regarding the email retention I found a [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_us&id=000323502&type=1&mode=1) that states "For every email with attachment sent from an org, records are created in the EmailMessage object and the Attachment object"  and "If attachments were not deleted by an end-user, attachments can be found in the search result records for up to 30 days".

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and that article. How do I see the emails in the EmailMessage ? Also, just to make myself clear : I am speaking of emails received in an Email Service, from an external non-Salesforce email sender. I'm not sure if that is what you're talking about. I've been doing queries of the EmailMessage object in Workbench and haven't been able to find the email I am hoping to find.